# How to create instances with runtime dependencies using Koin?

Tags: kotlin, koin

I'm experimenting with Koin while building a Kotlin-based HTTP server.

I'm using a framework in which you code your desired behavior by extending some framework-provided abstract classes and fill in your implementation logic at various points in the component's lifecycle (similar to Android). At some point in the component's lifecycle, a framework-specific resource (exposed as a field) becomes initialized and available for use.

My problem is that I need this field in order to create the instances returned from my Koin module.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
interface MyInteractor

class MyComponent : FrameworkComponent(), KoinComponent {    
    // "helper" is a field local to this class and used as 
    // an injection parameter
    private val myInteractor: MyInteractor by inject { parametersOf(helper) } 

    private val myModule = module { 
        single<MyInteractor> { (helper: FrameworkField) ->
            // return an instance of MyInteractor using "helper"
        }
    }

    // lifecycle method
    override fun start() {
        startKoin(listOf(myModule))
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work though as "helper" isn't initialized until later in the component's lifecycle.

I've managed to work around this by stashing the "helper" in the Koin context and then retrieving it from the context while making various instances, but this feels clumsy and repetitive. I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to go about this.

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse there is

in your module, define your module like below,

```
 single { (args: Array<Any>) -> SignInViewModel(args[0] as SignInCallback) }
```

and then in your activity, pass argument value like below,

```
val signInModel by inject<SignInViewModel>(parameters = getDefinitionParams(this@SignInFragment))
```

and getDefinitionParams() like this

```
 fun getDefinitionParams(vararg any: Any) : ParameterDefinition{
        return object : ParameterDefinition {
            override fun invoke() = parametersOf(any)
        }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful, Happy coding :D

Comment: Can you please mark this as an Accepted answer if that works for you?

Comment: It works just fine in koin 2.x, but if you're in 3.x its easier just use: viewModel<SignInViewModel>(), or depend on get() for parameters definition. Cheers.